# Why can't I enter more inputs after entering bigger than 9 x values?

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n;
    int x;
    int h=24;
    int s=9;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n>0)
    {
        n=n-1;
        scanf("%d",&x);
        while (x<=9)
        {
            if (x==1)
                printf("2\n");
            if (x==2)
                printf ("3\n");
            if (x==3)
                printf ("5\n");
            if (x==4)
                printf("7\n");
            if (x==5)
                printf("11\n");
            if (x==6)
                printf("13\n");
            if (x==7)
                printf("17\n");
            if (x==8)
                printf("19\n");
            if (x==9)
                printf("23\n");
            break;
        }
        while (23<h<542 && x>9)
        {
            h=h+1;
            if ( (h%2)!=0 && (h%3)!=0 && (h%5)!=0 && (h%7)!=0 && (h%11)!=0 && (h%13)!=0 && (h%17)!=0 && (h%19)!=0 && (h%23)!=0 )
            {
                s=s+1;
                if (x==s)
                    printf("%d\n",h);

            }     
       }        
 }
```

}

The question for the code is to enter n which will be the number of the following inputs. Each input must give the xth prime number.
example:

input:
3
,4
,20
,50
output:
7
,71
,229.

x can be between 1 and 100. (the first 100th prime numbers)
Now my problem is with x>9.after entering one value for it, it won't accept anymore values for x.

I would like to know why this happens and how to fix it.

I'm also very new to programming and haven't learned arrays yet.(I know scanfs aren't the best thing but that's all I've learned so far)

Comment: `23<h<542` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: The `while (x <= 9)` loop never loops, because it always executes `break` at the end. Why not just use `if (x <= 9)`?

Comment: You never reset `h` and `s` after computing the first input; move those declarations to the inside of the first `while` loop and the code will sort of do what you want.  You need to change `23<h<542` to `23<h && h<542`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
while (23<h<542 && x > 9)
```

is creating an infinite loop when `x` is greater than `9`. `23 < h < 542` doesn't test whether `h` is between `23` and `542`. That expression is equivalent to `(23 < h) < 542`. `(23 < h)` is `1` if `23` is less than `h`, which is always the case because `h` starts as `24` and the loop increases it. And `1` is always less than `542`.

What you want is:

```
if (x > 9) {
    while (h < 542) 
        ...
    }
}
```

There's no need to test `x` each time through the loop, because it never changes within the loop. And there's no need to test `23 < h`, because that's always true.

When you do need to check whether a variable is between two numbers, the way to do it is with `23 < h && h < 542`.

Another problem is that when you enter multiple numbers higher than 9, you're not resetting `h` and `s` back to their initial values before the `while` loop that looks for higher primes. You should initialize those values right before the loop, not just at the top of the program.

You can also make use of cascaded if/else if/else so you don't need to test `x` at the end (or you could use `switch/case`).

Here's the full rewritten program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int n;
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n>0) {
        n=n-1;
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if (x==1) {
            printf("2\n");
        } else if (x==2) {
            printf ("3\n");
        } else if (x==3) {
            printf ("5\n");
        } else if (x==4) {
            printf("7\n");
        } else if (x==5) {
            printf("11\n");
        } else if (x==6) {
            printf("13\n");
        } else if (x==7) {
            printf("17\n");
        } else if (x==8) {
            printf("19\n");
        } else if (x==9) {
            printf("23\n");
        } else {
            int h = 24;
            int s = 9;
            while (h<542) {
                h=h+1;
                if ( (h%2)!=0 && (h%3)!=0 && (h%5)!=0 && (h%7)!=0 && (h%11)!=0 && (h%13)!=0 && (h%17)!=0 && (h%19)!=0 && (h%23)!=0 ) {
                    s=s+1;
                    if (x==s) {
                        printf("%d\n",h);
                    } 
                }     
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/0SYSgn)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested the new code but I'm still getting the same results. The only difference is that I can input the other values but there are no outputs for them.

Comment: Found another problem: you weren't reinitializing `h` and `s` for each number the user entered.